# Keycloak Still Login with gmail if close browser new tab or window | Remove session another device

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak

use plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/ssr

I have a problem login with gmail, where if I close the browser all tabs really close the browser there is no opening the tab / browser for authentication from keycloak ssr asking for login again, I hope if after logging with gmail in and a menu appears even though closing the browser it is still logged in or remove session logged in on another device. like the picture below:

[image]

this trace video :
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31697177/222651372-d69b1b41-70f0-4cb7-992d-f0f87f0dae23.mp4